# I have an error in SQL syntax when i run a specific script to query various things from a moodle MySQL database

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I did an initial debagging to the script below but the output shows this error :

***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mdl' at line 1***

***The script which i am trying to run to my SQL client (Dbeaver 7.3.5) is :***

> ```
> SELECT u.id, ra.roleid,
> CONCAT(u.lastname, ' ', u.firstname) AS 'Student'
> ,COUNT(l.id) AS 'Actions'
> ,l.component "Module type"
> ,l.objectid "Module ID"
> ,CASE 
>   WHEN l.component = 'mod_url' THEN (SELECT u.name FROM mdl_url AS u WHERE u.id = l.objectid )
>   WHEN l.component = 'mod_resource' THEN (SELECT r.name FROM mdl_resource AS r WHERE r.id = l.objectid )
>   WHEN l.component = 'mod_forum' THEN (SELECT f.name FROM mdl_forum AS f WHERE f.id = l.objectid )
>   WHEN l.component = 'mod_quiz' THEN (SELECT q.name FROM mdl_quiz AS q WHERE q.id = l.objectid )
>   WHEN l.component = 'mod_questionnaire' THEN (SELECT q.name FROM mdl_questionnaire AS q WHERE q.id = l.objectid )
> END AS 'Module name'
>  
> ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) FROM mdl_groups AS g
> JOIN mdl_groups_members AS m ON g.id = m.groupid WHERE g.courseid = l.courseid AND m.userid = u.id) "user_groups"
>  
> ,(SELECT s.name 
>   FROM mdl_course_modules AS cm 
>   JOIN mdl_course_sections AS s ON s.course = cm.course AND s.id = cm.section 
>   WHERE cm.id = l.contextinstanceid) AS "Section name"
>  
> FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log AS l  
> JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = l.userid
> JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.userid = l.userid 
>   AND ra.contextid = (SELECT id FROM mdl_context WHERE instanceid = l.courseid AND contextlevel = 50) 
> WHERE l.courseid = %%COURSEID%%
>   AND l.component IN ('mod_url', 'mod_resource', 'mod_forum', 'mod_quiz', 'mod_questionnaire') 
>   %%FILTER_STARTTIME:l.timecreated:>%% %%FILTER_ENDTIME:l.timecreated:<%%
>  
> GROUP BY u.id, l.component
> ORDER BY u.lastname, u.firstname
> ```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not fix the syntax error?

Comment: perhaps you have a random mdl word in your editor?

Comment: The problem initially was incompatibility with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. I have disabled that and now it seems that there is nothing more to debug but only to correct this syntax error. I dont really have a clue of what could possibly fires a syntax error. I will try again line by line in response with the MySQL version : (